# How to get dynamic NR parameter in AWK command at shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, curl, awk, sh

I have txt file like this:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

I want to take these datas step by step for example first ı will get " 1 " and put it a varible and then get " a " put it in a varible and run a curl command

I mean first first row first column then fisrt row second column then second row first column .....

ı wrote a script in below but not working, it turns null varible for b and c

```
#!/bin/sh
for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
                echo $i
        b=$(awk 'NR==$i { print $1}' a.txt)
        c=$(awk 'NR==$i { print $2}' a.txt)
        echo $b
        echo $c
curl -X POST \
-H "X-netmera-api-key: xxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '[
    {
        "deviceToken" : "$b",
        "platform" : "1",
        "extId" : "$c"
    }
]' \
https://xxxx.xxxxx.com/rest/3.0/xxxxx

done
```

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/) as the approach you describe doesn't seem to make sense. Tell us what you want to do (as opposed to how you want to do it) and we can help you.

Comment: BTW, the right tool for the job (re: generating correctly quoted and escaped JSON) is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw `awk` away; it isn't necessary here.

```
while read -r b c; do
  curl -X POST \
   -H "X-netmera-api-key: xxxxxxxxxx" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d "[
        {
          \"deviceToken\" : \"$b\",
          \"platform\" : \"1\",
          \"extId\" : \"$c\"
        }
       ]" \
   https://xxxx.xxxxx.com/rest/3.0/xxxxx
done < a.txt
```

You shouldn't be trying to generate JSON dynamically like this, but that's an issue for another question.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass variables to awk with -v and so:

```
b=$(awk -v varb=$i 'NR==varb { print $1}' a.txt)
```

Here we are setting the awk variable varb equal to the i variable of your bash loop.